# Multiple Grand Totals in Birt

Tags: java, birt

I am trying to make a dynamic report with a subtotals in BIRT with the following format

```
Field 1| Field 2|| Jan  |  Feb | March ||Before Feb 1| After Feb 1| Total
   A   |    B   ||  2   |   4  |    4  ||            |      8     |  10
```

I am using a crosstab. I have managed to get it working by editing the Gui but I can't generate the same output programmicaly. I need to generate the output as the report fiels are dynamic.

I have three measures

```
measure("beforeDateKilos") this is from a ComputedColumn
measure("afterDateKilos") this is from a ComputedColumn
measure("kilos");
```

In the GUI I added a grid to the grand total cells.

```
 
------Grand Total Column---------------
| ----------Grid--------------------  |
| |Before Feb 1| After Feb 1| Total | |
| |  2         |      8     |  10   | |
| ----------------------------------- |
---------------------------------------
```

The only way I can find to create the grand total is to call the following method:

```
CrosstabCellHandle columnTotalCrosstabCellHandle =  
xtabHandle.addGrandTotal(ICrosstabConstants.COLUMN_AXIS_TYPE);
```

Calling just produces one column and only the heading column can be changed. How do I generate a grand total column with a custom output or that has sub totals?

Comment: I am looking into extends CrossTab.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be on the right track, but I think this will help you at least to get on the right direction.
In the binding tab for that Grand Total Grid, select the "Report Item " radio button and bind it to the appropriate table which has your sub-total and other values you need. You may need to provide appropriate table binding label for your convienience. Now you can use all the fields available on that table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply do you know how to bind the aggregations to the cross tabs using the Java API?

Comment: You bind the aggregation, in BIRT when you add it to the report.                                                                                                     Select the aggregation, in the 'Property Editor' select the tab 'Binding'